# How to add a specific amount of loop cuts without the mouse

Tags: mouse, modeling

I am working on a blender project where I have a cube in which I want 14 loop cuts.
Blender 2.8 can do exact loop cuts with scrolling the mouse.
My Question is: Can you do this without a Mouse?

Comment: Sorry if it is short, it is my first Question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of completeness (Blender 2.8+):

If you have no mouse wheel you can use <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> to increase and decrease the number of loop cuts.

(If you want to zoom in and out in the viewport or node editor then you have to use <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad -</kbd> instead.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I never knew page up/down can simulate mouse scrolls.

Comment: @math if you find an answer that works best for you, you can always change the accepted answer. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. Here's how:

- with the element selected, hit <kbd>→ Tab</kbd>
- hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and hover your mouse to activate the loop visualiser
- hit <kbd>5</kbd> (if you want 5 cuts)
- hit <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>
- enter a number between `-1` and `1` to define the offset of the cuts, or use the arrow keys to move them in increments
- hit <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Try using CTRL + R to add the loop cut(s), and type the number of cuts you need
[image: 14 loop cuts]

Hit enter (return key) to create them.
[image: Preview and move]

Move the cuts with your arrow keys Press enter again to apply the movement.

Further reading at: [blender loop cut and slide manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/loopcut_slide.html)

Answer (score 4):

Besides the keyboard shortcuts explained already in the other answers you can use the tool options.

Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to create a loop cut.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and use the tool options on the bottom left of the screen to set the Loop cut the way you need it.

[image]